# SymmetricDS Bi-directional Push Group Link

Tags: symmetricds

I want to create bi-directional push group link, but always appear error 'PushService - Cannot push to node 'store-001' in the group 'store'. The sync.url is blank'

Help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there's missing sync.url property in the .properties file under engines directory if you're using a standalone symmetricds installation.

Comment: Nope, it all configured. But when i change all group link to push, it happened.

Comment: well, you can't just switch in the middle of syncing. clean all DBs, reconfigure symmetricds at central and retry

Comment: Aha, thank you. OOT, the data already pointed to the node but the node is not registered yet, and need to resync. How?

Comment: issue a reload event: https://sourceforge.net/p/symmetricds/discussion/739236/thread/337faa20/